# Database Project deploy with GenerateDropsIfNotInProject drops users that are in the database project

Tags: database-project

I have created a Database project with users:

TimTestUser.user.sql

```
CREATE USER [TimTestUser]
      FOR LOGIN [TimTestLogin]
```

and also have created a Login in a server project
TimTestLogin.login.sql

```
CREATE LOGIN TimTestLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'tim'
```

In the Database.sqldeployment I have selected:
generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database

When I deploy the DB project <strike>the users get dropped and then re-created, and this causes the Login to User link to fail and the user becomes orphaned.</strike>

Update:

When I deploy the DB project  Revoke connect to [TimTestUser] is generated

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this issue when using a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2013 by checking the "Import permissions" option (unchecked by default) when importing your database into the project.

Doing so creates a Permissions.sql file in the Security directory that includes the GRANT statements for each of your users:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO [MyUser] AS [dbo];
```

Comment: You might be interested to know that this advice as described doesn't always work. No .sqlpermissions file is created when importing a database that definitely does have relevant permissions. I cannot see a reason why not.

Comment: Notice, I had to add this line right under my CREATE USER line.  Adding a Permissions.sql file to the Security directory did not work.  I don't have any .sqlpermissions file and I did not Import permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the sqlpermissions solution above to work. Adding a grant permission statement to the user script worked for me however. For example:

`GRANT CONNECT TO [TimTestUser]`

Answer (score 1):

After trying to add a GRANT CONNECT as a post-deployment script, and trying to regenerate a whole new .sqlproj after manually setting up the connection privilege in SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I discovered that [BunnyStrider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2690556/bunnystrider) was correct: you have to add the GRANT CONNECT to the same script file that the CREATE USER is in. Here is the code, all in one file named TimTestUser.sql in the Security folder:

```
CREATE USER [TimTestUser]
      FOR LOGIN [TimTestLogin];
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [TimTestUser];
GO
```

I then confirmed this code by removing the import-wizard-generated Permissions.sql that contained the GRANT CONNECT, and also the post-deployment script that I had added, and the connection still worked. I then re-generated the deployment script (double-clicked the *.Publish.xml file and clicked Generate Script) and verified that the REVOKE CONNECT TO [TimTestUser] was gone.

We are using SQL Server 2014, with Visual Studio 2012 and SSDT 11.1.50717.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server implicitly grants Connect when creating a User

```
CREATE USER [TimTestUser]
```

When the db project builds and deploys, it can't find the CONNECT permission in the the Database.sqlpermissions file

The solution to this is to explicitly set the Connect Database.sqlpermissions

```
<PermissionStatement Action ="GRANT">
  <Permission>CONNECT</Permission>
  <Grantee>TimTestUser</Grantee>
</PermissionStatement>
```

Comment: You can edit these permissions in the file 'Database.sqlpermissions' that is located in the 'Properties' folder of the Database Project in Visual Sudio